# What's __nss_passwd_lookup() call that I see in profiler output about?

Tags: c++, linux, linux-kernel, gperftools

I'm using [gperftools](https://github.com/gperftools/gperftools) to profile a C++ application, which was compiled using GCC 5.4.0 (with -O3).

The code is highly optimized, so I don't see a lot of branches in the output, but there's a branch called **__nss_passwd_lookup()**, which takes significant amount of time:

[image]

My only guess is that it's related to memory allocation somehow.

Operating system: Ubuntu 16.04 x86_64, Kernel: 4.8.

Comment: You might try [*this*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/378024/23771).

Answer (score 1):

Some assembly functions in glibc occasionally have this issue (e.g. memcpy or memset). Consider installing libc6-dbg package. Also please try golang version of pprof tool (go get github.com/google/pprof).

Comment: Can you clarify what "this issue" is?

Comment: What I mean is I've seen asm functions from glibc such as strlen being incorrectly reported as __nss_<whatever>. I never bothered to figure out why.